# Vue Reduce method function is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm trying to calculate the total balances returned from the array of objects of clients stored in Firebase.

I'm using Vue for this project. Right now, it's not working as it's returning `NaN`

```
computed: {
    totalOwed() {
      if (this.clients && !this.loading) {
        // console.log(this.clients);
        this.clients.reduce((total, client) => {
          return total + parseFloat(client.balance.toString());
        }, 0);
      }
      return null;
    },
    ...mapState(["clients", "user", "loading"])
  }
```

When I used the `totalOwed` computed property in the template, I got a `NaN` as the value.
Here is the [Github link](https://github.com/peoray/client-panel) and [Live site](https://reverent-dubinsky-998ac1.netlify.com/)

Code can be found in the `Clients.vue` inside of `src/components/clients` directory

Comment: what is ```clients.balance``` and why do you call ```toString``` on it?

Comment: You aren't returning a value within the if block.

Comment: @grodzi, client.balance is what gets returned from firebase. It's an object, so I have to make reference to the property I want which is balance

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong data structure. Shouldn't it be `client.balance.stringValue`?

```js
-  return total + parseFloat(client.balance.toString()); // delete this line
+  return total += parseFloat(client.balance.stringValue); // add this line
```

Plus add `return` before `this.clients.reduce...`

Comment: the equal is unecessary, op operates inside a reduce (total being the accumulator)
However op forgot to return the total (and always returns null...)

Comment: @grodzi thanks. Still thinks `+=` is more readable/understandable.

Comment: `+  return total += parseFloat(client.balance.stringValue);`
What does `stringValue` mean?

Comment: And also it worked by just adding a return to the reduce function
`return this.clients.reduce((total, client) => ...`

Comment: @Peoray it is just his data structure: `{ client: { balance: {stringValue: "100"}}}` I checked that in his project.